# How to filter custom field in graphene django?

Tags: python, django, graphene-django

```
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import Question

class QuestionType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ("id", "question_text")

    extra_field = graphene.String()

    def resolve_extra_field(self, info):
        return "hello!"
```

On my Query
`result = Question.objects.filter(extra_field='hello!')`

Error Cannot resolve keyword 'extra_field' into field.

How can I filter the extra_field in my Query?